# Why does my Google Cloud Function kick up CORS policy issues when I add a console log with a reference to variable?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a basic node.js cloud function. It accepts a request and just returns the body of the message; it's not working correctly and I'm trying to debug with console logs.

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  console.log("req: ");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {
    let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
    let rets ={};
    rets['message'] = message;
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(rets));
  }

};
```

The above works fine. But if I change the console log line to this:

```
  console.log("req: " + JSON.stringify(req) );
```

I get the following error:

Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-delta-xxxxx-1111111.cloudfunctions.net/getEvents' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I just can't figure out why the console statement would affect the CORS stuff. I added the checks in the above code to try and fix these CORS issues

EDIT 1:

I notice that I don't get the CORS error if I instead console log the body of the request? The below works fine

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body) );
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

Try to turn on CORS mode on the client side.